# Can Word be put in Writing Mode?

Tags: technique, software, tools, microsoft-word

I think the title of this question deserves some explanation.

For a number of reasons I am using Microsoft Word, Office 365 version.
I subscribe to the [writing versus editing technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/376/47378). I clear my mind by laying down all my ideas and come back later to edit and organize them.

Word keeps on interrupting my flow to helpfully tell me that "first hand" should really be "first-hand", or possibly "firsthand"; that I should really use a comma after this "but", etc.

I do not like these distractions. I disable the "Grammar and Refinements" settings during the writing phase, and re-enable them during the editing phase. As you will see in the screenshot below, the settings window is clearly not meant to be used that way. There are a large number of checkboxes that need to be manually unchecked to put the software in "writing mode".

[image: Screenshot of Word Grammar Settings window which shows a large number of checkboxes controlling individual suggestion options.]

Am I using Word incorrectly? Is there an easy way to toggle between writing and editing modes?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this sentence as an example:
[image]

I can go into **MS Word Options** -> Select **Proofing** and scroll to the bottom and completely turn of grammar and spelling checks for a specific open document.  This setting will persist in this document, so I only need to do it once.
[image]

After ticking those two boxes at the bottom and returning to my document, we see that MS Word's helpfulness is stopped and I am left with only what I type.

[image]